# Android: button click event not working for simple multiplication app

Tags: android

Good Day,

I am new to android and using Eclipse 3.7.2. I have been following examples on the net (the so-called "add two numbers" examples but, after discovering that AbsoluteLayout is deprecated, I am using RelativeLayout and basically going from scratch. The app basically is supposed to take two numbers (how far a guy went and how much he is paid per mile) and pop out total pay.

The app compiles fine and starts up in the emulator. I get excited! Pop in 2 numbers and hit the button. Nothing. I look and see that there's no errors happening.

Am I missing something with my button listener? Here is the Java code I've put in (updated 5:27pm 10.31.2012):

```
package com.example.wing_it;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText mile,driver;
Button button1;
TextView tv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mile= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mile);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pay);
    driver= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.driver);
    button1.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    }


public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
class clicker implements Button.OnClickListener
{
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    {
        String a,b;
        Integer vis;
        a = mile.getText().toString();
        b = driver.getText().toString();
        vis = Integer.parseInt(a)*Integer.parseInt(b);
        tv.setText(vis.toString());
        }
    }
}       
}
```

The XML code is as such:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/miles"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:text="@string/paypermile"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="@string/compute" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
    android:text="@string/pay"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/mile"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/driver"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mile"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/totalpay"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.wing_it"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application>

</manifest>
```

I have the value of the result textview set to nothing (just a blank) in the strings.xml. It was set to '0' and I removed that to see if it would make a difference. Still, nothing.

Is there something I am overlooking here? Thank you for looking. :)

Comment: You don't have a clue about what you are doing, do you?

Comment: There's a learning curve involved, unfortunately. Eclipse isn't terribly helpful and the trouble I am finding is that while it lets me execute the code, I've seen nothing but bugs today, like the adb server not starting so I had to figure out how to restart that lol. Like I said, trying to help myself but running into a roadblock with something that doesn't tell me what the problem is. I am a beginner who is trying. :)

Comment: I should probably also point out that it looks like others have experienced what I am and when I go to check for something similar, I don't see. I want to mark the question answered if only I can fix this problem and get it to run. Oddly enough, it's easier in javascript on a website but who knew. I'm living and learning. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    public void onCreate() {
     button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
     button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
       // code here
    }
```

it's hard to read your code, but this should work (sorry if i have spelling errors, i cannot cut/paste from my code (on another machine)

Comment: Although this would work in this case, it is not a recommended solution if you have multiple buttons in the `Activity` which are going to have different `OnClickListener`s.

Comment: well, if that were the case i'd have a `case` statement switching on the id's of the buttons.

Comment: Which, at least according to me, would make it a lot harder to read the code. Setting a different OnClickListener for each button is a much cleaner solution, instead of using switch & case. It will give more flexibility.

Comment: Hi there, well, only have one button. Let me understand: do I make yet a second public void onCreate statement just for the button because there's already a public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { statement. I simply added button1.setOnClickListener(this); to the lines under that onCreate(Bundle...etc etc) statement and then changed the public void onClick statement to include another 'view'. Ran it and nothing happened. However, before that happened, Eclipse made me rename the onClick method to onClick1. Should I have two separate onCreate statements? Thanks.

Comment: one way or the other there needs to be an `onClick()` that one or more buttons goto for their click processing. i suggested having your class implement OnClickListener interface (which has an implementable `onClick()` function), or you can have an annonymous inner function for each button that implements the `onClick()'. six one way, half a dozen the other.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I am a newbie for sure and had to resort to installing IntelliJ 11, which seemed to be a lot more thoughtful in terms of hints and clarity...and then went back over to Eclipse to make sure the problem wasn't Eclipse (because I had updated the version I have and you would have thought the world had changed in a day lol!)

Anyway, I only had to change a couple of lines of code after I went back over it. Turns out I didn't need a class for the clicker at all. I just needed to incorporate the "new button.OnClickListener" as the argument for setting the OnClickListener. I'm truly living and learning and it's good day when you learn. Thank you, Simon and David M. Have a good day!

Here is the code which now works for anyone to reference:

```
package com.example.wing_it;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText mile,driver;
Button button1;
TextView tv;
private double x,y,z;
private Button calculate;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mile= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mile);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pay);
    driver= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.driver);
    calculate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    calculate.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
    {public void onClick
                (View  v) { calculate();}});
}
private void calculate()
{
    x=Double.parseDouble(mile.getText().toString());
    y=Double.parseDouble(driver.getText().toString());
    z=x*y;
    tv.setText(Double.toString(z));

    }


public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Glad to see that you worked it out. I think you should read some more Android Developing Tutorials so that you get a hang about what you actually are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You have two methods in your interface for some reason...
When the button is clicked, **it will call the one named `onClick`**, not `onClick1`.

```
class clicker implements Button.OnClickListener
{
public void onClick1(View v)
{
    String a,b;
    Integer vis;
    a = mile.getText().toString();
    b = driver.getText().toString();
    vis = Integer.parseInt(a)*Integer.parseInt(b);
    tv.setText(vis.toString());
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Should be:

```
class clicker implements Button.OnClickListener
{
public void onClick(View v)
{
    String a,b;
    Integer vis;
    a = mile.getText().toString();
    b = driver.getText().toString();
    vis = Integer.parseInt(a)*Integer.parseInt(b);
    tv.setText(vis.toString());
}
```

Note the change in the method name from `onClick1` to `onClick`.

However, you don't need to use a nested class to implement OnClickListener, you can instead create the OnClickListener "on the fly", by using what is known as `inner classes`.

This is done like this:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        String a,b;
        Integer vis;
        a = mile.getText().toString();
        b = driver.getText().toString();
        vis = Integer.parseInt(a)*Integer.parseInt(b);
        tv.setText(vis.toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello Simon, I modified the code and after having a pesky "adb is down" error and killing the server, I am now getting "the application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again." Is this just Eclipse giving me the gears today? LOL I can't even see if the change even worked.

Comment: @Shawn find out how to use the tool `adb logcat`, use it, find out what the exception is and post it here. You can also update your original post and add the code as it looks now.

Comment: code updated and added the manifest. I looked at the logcat, which I admit I've never used before, and saw two items: one was from dalvikvm that says "threadid=7: reacting to signal 3" and then a second message that says "Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'" but I cannot seem to locate either the directory (don't see it in my project) or after doing a search on traces.txt. Thanks for helping! Can't wait to see if it runs. Is this a foible of Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there's a bug in Android Studio itself. Close it and restart it and RUN your app again. It should work.